# If change in enthalpy is defined for a reaction going to completion, how is it measured for reactions that don't?

Tags: thermodynamics

I read that $\Delta H$ is the energy absorbed or released for a reaction going 100% to completion([here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112815/change-in-gibbs-free-energy-vs-change-in-enthalpy#:%7E:text=To%20start%20off%2C%20%CE%94G,change%20from%20reactants%20to%20products.)). However, what we would be measuring in a calorimeter would be the reaction going from initial products to equilibrium. So for reactions where K isn't very high, the heat released or absorbed wouldn't reflect $\Delta H$

Comment: "If change in enthalpy is defined for a reaction going to completion" who told you something like that?

Comment: @Mithoron I will link it here again https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112815/change-in-gibbs-free-energy-vs-change-in-enthalpy#:%7E:text=To%20start%20off%2C%20%CE%94G,change%20from%20reactants%20to%20products.

Comment: Additionally, chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/‌​… and khan academy (khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry/…) define $\Delta G$ for a reaction as $Gproducts-Greactants$ meaning in the final state, only the products exist, which implies 100% conversion. Since $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$, the initial and final states in that delta for all three quantities is going to be the same. So if $\Delta G$ for a reaction is defined for a particular final state(which those links imply), so would $\Delta H$

Comment: That was a rhetoric question, you know? I pointed your fallacy. You neither need an actual reaction happening nor its measurement, much less "going to completion". Such value is just an abstract.

Answer (score 2):

For incomplete irreversible reactions, you have to use the conversion $X$ of the limiting reagent:

$$\Delta H=n_{Ao}\;X\;\Delta\overline{H}^{\;o}$$

For reversible reactions, you have to use the conversion at equilibrium $X_e$:

$$\Delta H=n_{Ao}\;X_{e}\;\Delta\overline{H}^{\;o}$$

In both cases, $\Delta\overline{H}^{\;o}$ is the standard molar enthalpy of the reaction, and $n_{Ao}$ is the initial amount of limiting reagent A present.

Note that for complete irreversible reactions (such as a combustion with excess oxygen), the conversion is implicitly omitted since its value for such case is 1 or 100%.

For a reversible reaction of the form:

$$\ce{aA + bB <=> cC + dD}$$

$X_e$ can be calculated from the following equation, given reaction conditions, initial concentrations, and equilibrium constant $K_C$ at reaction temperature $T$:

$$K_C=\left[\left(\frac{C_{Ao}}{1+\epsilon\;X_e}\right)\left(\frac{P}{P_o}\right)\left(\frac{T_o}{T}\right)\right]^{\Delta n}\;\frac{\left(\frac{C_{Co}}{C_{Ao}}+\frac{c}{a}X_e\right)^c\;\left(\frac{C_{Do}}{C_{Ao}}+\frac{d}{a}X_e\right)^d}{\left(1-X_e\right)^a\;\left(\frac{C_{Bo}}{C_{Ao}}-\frac{b}{a}X_e\right)^b}$$

If the reaction conditions are such that volume, pressure, and temperature all remain constant, only 1 reactant and 1 product are involved, only A is initially present, and the stoichiometric coefficients of A and C are both 1, the expression is simplified a lot, since we would have the reaction:

$$\ce{A<=>C}$$

With the expression:

$$K_C=\frac{X_e}{1-X_e}\implies X_e=\frac{K_C}{1+K_C}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141367/discussion-on-answer-by-sam202-if-change-in-enthalpy-is-defined-for-a-reaction-g).